# JasperReports: Class not found exception when filling a JasperReport with data

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a problem with JasperReports library/JasperSoft Studio. I am working on an OSGi project, and I am implementing reports generation. I have my data model inside an OSGi bundle:

```
public final class TodaysTransactionData extends OverviewData {

    private final String district;
    private final LocalDate date;
    private final String subdivision;
    private final Boolean isAutomatic;
    private final List< PaymentData > cashPayments;
    private final List< PaymentData > transfers;
    // Getters, setters, constructors
}
```

and:

```
public class PaymentData {

    private final String referenceNumber;
    private final float claimAmount;
    private final float paidAmount;
    private final float totalPaid;
    private final String paymentStatus;
    private final LocalDate paymentDate;

    // Getters, setters, constructors
}
```

I have almost finished designing my report in JasperSoft Studio, but I have runned into a problem - JasperSoft Studio had no knowledge about my data classes. I have found an answer, which suggested to create a tiny jar with required classes, so I did that. Here's the structure:

```
car.manufacturer.base
│
└───reports.datamodel
    │
    ├── OverviewData
    ├── TodaysTransactionData
    ├── PaymentData
    │
    └───descriptor
        ├── Descriptor
        ├── TodaysTransactionDescriptor
```

The packages and names of the classes match my data model that's defined in the OSGi app.

After I have created this Jar, I have added it to the Java build path. Then I successfully compiled my report and added it to the classpath of the OSGi app.

This is how I create the PDF file

```
        String templateInputStream = FrameworkUtil.getBundle( this.getClass() ).getBundleContext().getBundle().getResource( "/car/manufacturer/base/reports/template/TodaysTransactionTemplate.jasper" ).getFile();
        JasperReport carReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject( getFileFromResources( templateInputStream ) );

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource carCashPaymentsSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource( todaysTransactionData.getCashPayments() );
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource carTransfersSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource( todaysTransactionData.getTransfers() );
        
        Map< String, Object > parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put( "PAYMENTS_OVERVIEW", todaysTransactionData );
        parameters.put( "CLIENT", getClient().getName() );
        parameters.put( "CASH_PAYMENTS", carCashPaymentsSource );
        parameters.put( "TRANSFERS", carTransfersSource );
        
        JasperPrint carPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(carReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Where `todaysTransactionData` is an instance of `TodaysTransactionData` with two lists of `PaymentData`

When I'm trying to generate a PDF file, I get this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> car.manufacturer.base.reports.datamodel.TodaysTransactionData

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error
> evaluating expression for source text: msg("Received Payments Duration
> {0}", $P{PAYMENTS_OVERVIEW}.getDate().toString())

To clarify, `PAYMENTS_OVERVIEW` is a Java object, instance of `TodaysTransactionData`, that I'm passing to the report

`<parameter name="PAYMENTS_OVERVIEW" class="car.manufacturer.base.reports.datamodel.TodaysTransactionData"/>`

What am I doing wrong?